# Shapefile not showing up in QGIS, and doesn't give coordinates in (Lat, Lon) in R

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, r, coordinates

I am attempting to find the coordinates associated with the Traffic Analysis Zones from this survey.

When I open it in QGIS it shows up on the sidebar as a point, not a block, and when I open the shapefile in R it gives coordinates like this:

```
coordinates(shape2)

       [,1]    [,2]
0    2406734 1631930

1    2433452 1626985

2    2447257 1617579

3    2391080 1621358

4    2420945 1617582

5    2373529 1616181

6    2410228 1612591
```

Here is a link: http://www.surveyarchive.org/

Column: Raw Data, Row: Atlanta, then click on 2011

Also, I've realized it doesn't come with a .prj file. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Hi there. I have just downloaded the data as described and when I open the file in QGIS, I am presented with 1 shapefile in the directory called "taz", opening this file I am presented with a polygon shapefile with approximately 2024 records. Please could you expand your question describing exactly what you did?

Comment: I can make those coordinates show up in northeast Georgia using NAD83 State Plane Georgia West zone (US feet) (EPSG:2240). They don't match the statewide definitions I know about, nor UTM.

Answer (score 2):

The taz.shp looks like this in my QGIS

[image]

So the data are there but the download site does not seem to tell in which coordinate referance system the coordinates are. I would try if people announced on the Contacs page could help.

Comment: Assigning EPSG:2240 (as given by mkenndy) to the shapefile seems to put it in the right place.

Comment: Hey guys I was able to get in contact with those that created the TAZ and the coordinate system was NAD83 like user mkennedy said.

Comment: @SamTucker pease mark the answer as accepted.